# Replace a motherboard or try to move HDD to a new computer

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard

The motherboard on my HP P6214Y is fried and the local computer repair shop wants $300 to fix it (I paid $500 for it 1.5 years ago).  Should I order my own OEM motherboard from Hong Kong for about $170 and attempt the repair myself or buy a new HP for around $450 and try to move my old HDD to the new computer.  I have some programs on the HDD that I no longer have the installation disk for (including some downloaded programs).

Thoughts??

Thank you all!

Comment: Probably too localized, there's not really an objective and definite answer to that question. You also don't say how experienced you are with computer hardware (when it comes to replacing a motherboard), but that's the essence of the problem. If your motherboard is dead and you can get a cheap replacement, I'd definitely replace it if I were technically able to. Also, are you sure you don't have warranty left on the device?

Comment: I agree it's too localized, but if you go the OEM motherboard route, make sure it's going to fit in your existing case before you buy it.  HP often uses modified motherboards and custom case configurations that may or may not support a standard motherboard.

Comment: Which OS are you running? Are you skilled with hardware (do you think you could replace a motherboard)? Please update your question with these answers or your question will definitely be at risk for closure.

Comment: More than likely its just capacitors that need replaced on that motherboard, a cheap fix...http://www.badcaps.net/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running windows 7, you could replace the motherboard and boot the computer up and install the drivers you may need (without BSOD or any issues at all). If there are issues (if have done this numerous time with no issues), boot using a Windows live CD/Flash Drive and install the drivers (put the drivers on the flash drive). If you need help understanding this, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I don't think this is localized at all...it is a common dilemma nowadays repair versus replace.  Obviously I have never changed a motherboard before...but the first time I added RAM and a secondary HDD it initially appeared more daunting then what the task turned out to be.  So I was simply inquiring to see if a motherboard replacement  was simple enough task versus buying another computer.  The cost of a new motherboard is not localized (apparently this one is only available through Hong Kong) and the price of a new HP is essentially the same everywhere.

Comment: In any event thank you David for your help...too bad those that closed my previous thread couldn't give me 24 hours to respond (since my home computer is DEAD, I have to post from work)...

Comment: Replacing a motherboard is not easy if you do not know how things are connected. You will have to unplug every cord on the motherboard, take off the CPU and CPU cooler, take out the RAM, find and remove the screws that connect the motherboard to the case, remove the GPU (if you have a GPU card instead of an integrated GPU). You mus then put the other motherboard in-place, and plug everything back in. Also, **VERY IMPORTANT**, make sure you ground yourself before and during the replacement of the motherboard to make sure you do not shock anything, which would result is destroying the part.

Comment: This task would take me about 1.5-2.5 hours (while being careful), and I am a professional. Since you are inexperienced, it would take a little bit longer. Also, just as a side note, if it were a laptop, it would take a professional around 2-3 hours to replace a motherboard...

Comment: Thank you again David...I am considering doing it myself, while my computer repair experience to date has been limited to replacing a dial up modem, RAM and installing a new HDD...if I am careful I think I could handle this...my biggest concern is the removal and insertion of the processor...

Comment: The processor is actually very easy as long as you remember that it is fragile. There are little pins on the bottom of the processor that are easy to bend, and if you bend them, you have broken you processor (basically). There is going to be a lever on the side of the Processor (CPU) socket. you must release this lever before you can carefully lift the processor from the socket. [Here](http://whp-java.extweb.hp.com/ewfrf-JAVA/Doc/images/c01635737.jpg) is a picture of the motherboard. At the bottom of the CPU socket is the lever. Once you release it, you will know it is safe to lift the CPU.

Comment: If you have any questions while doing it, take a picture of whatever it is and show me. I will be happy to help. I would rather you ask, and do it correctly, than guess and break it... :) I mam on EDT, and I am normally on between 8am-5pm M-F. I am on while I am at work. :D

Answer (score 0):

The decision in the long run is your's, but from my perspective (been repairing computers for years) I would replace the motherboard. If you buy a new board, make sure that it is the exact one that is in your computer already, or you may end up having problems.

On the other hand, a computer that is 1.5 years old could have a little bit outdated technology. It would be easy to install the old HDD into the new computer to get the other programs. If you have the product keys, you can probably download trial software off of the company's website and enter the key to unlock the full version. If you lost the product keys, Lifehacker recently posted an article about something called ProduKey that can retrieve them after you install the HDD in the new computer.